# Calculate remaining time in php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, momentjs

Here I am stuck in a trouble which is showing calculate the remaining time from the database to the webpage. In my database, there is a table name task and 4 columns name, deadline, created date, and task. These column data are shown on the webpage by PHP. But I want to change the deadline column data by calculating the remaining time from the current date. The remaining time calculation is done in javascript. And the problem is when I send data to a PHP table it prints all data in a single row. I hope you understand my problem.
Here are some img [How data i want to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUEiO.png) but the data is showing like this [pic of data showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m23UQ.png)

```
    <?php
        include "db.php";
        $dateRem = array();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `task`";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("query failed ");
    
            $sr = 1;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {


            ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?= $sr++ ?>
            </td>
            <td >
            <?= $row['name']; ?>
            </td>
            <td id="data_rem"></td>
            <?php
                $dateRem[] = $row['deadline']; // array to store data
            ?>
            <td>
                <?= $row['created_date']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $row['task']; ?>
            </td>


        </tr>
        <?php

            }
            ?>
```

> javascript code

```
<script>
 function func() {
    var dateValue = <?php echo json_encode($dateRem); ?>;
    // console.log(dateValue);
    for(var i = 0; i < dateValue.length; i++){
        var date = Math.abs((new Date().getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0));
        // console.log(date);
        var date2 = Math.abs((new Date(dateValue[i]).getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0));
        // console.log(date2);
        var diff = date2 - date;

        var days = Math.floor(diff / 86400);

        var daysStr = days;
        if (days < 10) {
            daysStr = "0" + days;
        }
        if (days < 0) {
            daysStr = "00";
        }
        console.log(document.getElementById("data_rem").innerHTML += daysStr + " days left");
        // console.log(daysStr);
        // innerHTML = daysStr + " days left");
    }
 } func();
// var interval = setInterval(func, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: You should only need PHP to do this. How is `deadline` stored in the database? PHP has a `date_diff` function: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-date_diff-function/

Comment: at the time of insert data deadline date is also stored. But I want to do this in JavaScript.

Comment: OK it will be really easy to find days between two dates in PHP. Not sure why you would want to do this in Javascript, but anyway the reason it isn't working is because you are setting `id="data_rem"` multiple times, it is setting the first instance of the element.

Comment: then what is the way to do it?

Comment: You need to assign a unique id to each table row, assign a class name to the cell you want to change, then use javascript to find that cell and update the innerText.